# Is R an equivalence relation ? if yes, how?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$a$ is related to $b$ ($a\mathrel{R} b$) if and only $a\cdot b > 0$ over the set of non-zero rational numbers.  Is $R$ an equivalence relation? If yes how?

Comment: Let's see... definition of "equivalence relation"... it has to be REFLEXIVE... that means (a R a) for every real number a... that means a.a > 0 for all non-zero rational numbers.... CHECK!  "Equivalence relation" means two more things... What are they? How can they be interpreted in this case? After we interpret them, are those statements true for all non-zero rational numbers, or is at least one of them false for at least some choices of rational numbers? Good luck!

Comment: IMO it fails the transitive test if a  = 1, b = -1  and c= -3  ..am i wrong ?

Comment: @clydedacruz: No, that’s not a failure of transitivity, because $1$ is not related to $-1$: $1(-1)=-1<0$. HINT: Show that $a\mathrel{R}b$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ have the same algebraic sign.

Comment: Right .. i see my mistake . thanks @BrianM.Scott :)

Comment: @clydedacruz: You’re welcome.

Comment: Always work directly from the definitions . Does the binary relation R meet each and every condition in the def'n of an equivalence relation or not?

Answer (score 1):

Reflexive: For any non-zero rational $x$ we have $x^2 \geq 0$.

Symmetric: Multiplication is commutative, done.

Transitive: If $xRy$ and $yRz$, then all of $x, y, z$ have the same sign and hence $xRz$, and we are done.

This really just uses the properties of multiplication we know for $\mathbb{Q}$. Nothing too involved here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the quickest way to do this is to notice that $ab>0$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are either both positive or both negative, so there you have a partition of the set.